# "Resource is forbidden" connecting Power bi with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

I get this error message when I try to connect google analytics with Power BI

> Access to the resource is forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

**

### How to fix the Access to the Resource is Forbidden error

**

**1) Reset the Data Connection to Re-enter Credentials.**

1. Some users have confirmed that resetting the data connections for data sources fixed the “Access to the resource forbidden error.” To do that, click the File tab at the top left of Power BI.
2. Then click Options and settings on the menu.
3. Select Data Source Settings to open the window
4. Select the data source the “Access to the resource is forbidden” error arises for.
5. Then select the Clear Permissions option on the drop-down menu.
6. Press the Close button.
7. Thereafter, users can re-enter their credentials when they try to connect the required data sources.

**2) Select an Alternative Log-in Option to Connect to Data**

The “Access to the resource is forbidden” error can also arise when users select the wrong log-in options to connect their data sources with on the Access a window. For example, users trying to connect SharePoint Online via Power BI Desktop might need to select the Organizational account log-in option instead of Windows on the window shown directly below. So, try selecting an alternative log-in option through which to enter the log-in credentials.

https://windowsreport.com/access-to-resource-forbidden/