# power Bi connect to Graph access to the resource is forbidden

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, powerquery

I am trying to connect to the Graph Connector from Power BI, But i am getting Forbidden error
[Resource is forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypefY.png)
I tried few methods [Suggested post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158867/resource-is-forbidden-connecting-power-bi-with-google-analytics) it didn't help

Comment: Have you tried with reseting the data connection to re-enter credentials

Comment: it didn't work though, I have noticed in few Forums that Connection to Graph is not possible, it was working for sure but was removed due to securities reasons, I didnt find Document where it says we can't but I found an alternate [connect to graph with app permissions](https://minkus.medium.com/easily-connecting-between-power-query-power-bi-and-microsoft-graph-72333eb95a35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to connect to graph using a power query [Connect to Graph with power bi](https://minkus.medium.com/easily-connecting-between-power-query-power-bi-and-microsoft-graph-72333eb95a35)